# How can i set animation position in custom view for xml preview

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-animation, android-custom-view

I created a custom view that is invisible at first and it will be visible after the animation is completed.
the problem is when I want to use it in `xml` layout, the preview shows nothing because the view is invisible at first.
I created an `xml attribute` for disabling animation and when I disable the animation the `xml` preview shows the view.

**1. How can I make the view render, like when animation is disabled?**

I found a solution for this but I'm not satisfied with that:

I used the `xml` attribute that I made for disabling animation, with `app` and `tools` namespaces together, so the attribute with `tools` namespace overrides the `app` namespace for preview:

```xml
<com.example.example.MyCustomView

    ...

    app:animationEnabled="true"
    tools:animationEnabled="false">
```

**2. Can I Use `tools` namespace programmatically in custom view class?**

**3. Is there any proper solution for this?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

tools:visibility = true should do the trick while keeping android:visibility = "invisible"